# Windows 10 got 0x80070035 error code after of some time with a shared directory

Tags: windows-10, networking, macos, wireless-networking, network-shares

I have MacOS (El Capitan) and Windows 10.

I am able to share a directory from MacOS to Windows in peace. Therefore through Windows Explorer and using `Map network drive`, thus for example:

```
Drive : X  
Folder: \\Macbookpro_Name\directoryshared
```

Of course a login process is accomplished. I am able to read and write/create anything within the shared folder.

The problem is that after of some time the Drive mapped gets a red X and if I try to login again I receive

```
Error code: `0x80070035` 
The network path was not found.
```

What did do happen this? Both laptops have access to the network and internet yet.
The unique way to solve this situation is restarting windows 10 - but how solve this without restarting Windows?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1335068/cant-access-windows-shares-after-windows-10-build-1803-update) solution?

Comment: @Ramhound I have other machines in the network, if I turn off for few seconds the 'target' the other machines are going to get trouble